# Ruby Each Loop Variable Substitution

Tags: ruby, substitution

I'm trying to set all the values to 0 but the 3rd line (`send(x)`) is giving me problems. Seems right to me, but doesn't work. `x` is the car and name of the columns in Power. Any tips?

```
<% @cars.each do |x| %>
  <% @power = Power.find_by_user_id(@user) %>
  <% @power.send(x) = 0 %>
  <% @power.save %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what exactly is the value of cars?

Comment: What do you mean "all the values"? Also this should *definitely* not be in a view (assuming this is Rails-like).

Comment: say the @cars array contains c01 c02 c03 etc, and those are the names of the columns

Comment: @andrew, yea I'm going to clean this up and take it out of the view, i'm just getting it to work first

Comment: If I recall correctly past questions, you tend to set @vars in views, that's not idiomatic, use local variables. And never, ever, a save in a view.

Comment: tokland - will do, @variables are only set in controllers? variables with @ in views?

Comment: instance @variables are set in controllers and used in views. In views new variables should be local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `@cars` contains column names of `Power`, you need to `send` the setter method (i.e. with an `=` at the end). You also need to ensure you're passing a symbol to `send`.

```
@cars.each do |x|
  @power = Power.find_by_user_id(@user)
  @power.send(:"#{x}=", 0)
  @power.save
end
```

There's also not an obvious reason why you need to set or save `@power` in the loop, so it might be better as:

```
@power = Power.find_by_user_id(@user)
@cars.each do |x|
  @power.send(:"#{x}=", 0)
end
@power.save
```

Comment: Is it the only way to access dynamic attribute name? Does `ActiveRecord` class have method like `@power.get_attribute_by_name(x)`?

Comment: @galymzhan There is `write_attribute`, but that will bypass any custom-defined writer in the model.